# How to create a feature that detect age in text in different languages?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, text-mining

I have a text classification task in several languages. What aproach should use if I would like to create a feature that extract age from text if this are the possible classes: `18-24`,`25-34`,`35-49` and `50-xx"` and I have only tweets as a corpus. I all ready tried using all the tweets but with very low performance(0.66) any idea of how to aproach this task?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you already have the age associated with each tweet?

Comment: Yes. The problem is the low performance 0.51% any idea of how to push toward this?. I guess with more features but what about some pattern?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is still a research task, I suggest several links to scientific papers (links and the following summary are mostly taken from 'related work' section of [our paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20191220181718/https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/opredelenie-demograficheskih-atributov-polzovateley-mikroblogov) - unfortunately, in Russian, so I edited Google translation a little).

So, take a look at these works (marked by year): [2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20160617034418/http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICWSM/09/paper/viewPDFInterstitial/208/537), [2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20160101182151/https://csc-869-mlog.googlecode.com/files/p37-rao.pdf), [2011](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Claudia-Peersman/publication/221615645_Predicting_age_and_gender_in_online_social_networks/links/09e4150cb2d78bda25000000/Predicting-age-and-gender-in-online-social-networks.pdf), [2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20150412051417/http://depot.knaw.nl:80/13345/1/nguyen-icwsm2013.pdf), [2014](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7051893).

In summary: you should find or create tagged corpora and use supervised machine learning with the following features:

1. text features: n-grams over words and characters,
2. stylistic features: parts of speech, slang, the average sentence length, punctuation, acronyms, emoticons, etc.
3. social network features: the number of friends a user, the number of posts displayed on the page of the user, the total number of posts, the average number of comments for a post of the user.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and thanks for the references. In fact I all ready have a baseline of this, the problem is it's low performance (0.5104 %) of acuracy. We are using RF, I guees with more features this performance would increase. Any idea of how to push this perfomance?.

Comment: I was thinking something easy with regex for english. Do you think this is possible?.

Comment: Just a few thoughts: 
1) are you sure that it is underfitting, not overfitting - have you checked performance on train data?
2) take a look at performance for each class - maybe your data isn't well separated. If you are not stucked with these ranges, maybe adjustment can help
3) have you optimized hyperparameters (number of trees)?

Comment: what about regex? I didn't get you

Comment: Thanks for the remarks, I dont think this is overfitting since we are using cross validation k-fold. This is the current setup of the RF classifier (`rbf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10000, criterion='entropy', max_depth=10000, max_leaf_nodes=None, bootstrap=True, oob_score=False, n_jobs=1, random_state=None, verbose=0, min_density=None, compute_importances=None))`

Comment: I was thinking on extracting some pattern with some regex. Let's say "advberbs denote age", extract the count of all adverbs?

Comment: I mean that the reason of bad performance can be overfitting: your classifier predict train data well, but not test. Take a look at this perfect paper: http://www.centurion.link/w/_media/programming/a_few_useful_things_to_know_about_machine_learning.pdf

Comment: I still don't understand what regex do here? Yes, feature like 'count of adverbs in text' can be useful - it is stylistic feature from the above list.